# While login ADFS getting Error- System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size

Tags: java, spring, saml, adfs

The Federation Service encountered an error while processing the SAML authentication request.

Additional Data

Exception details:

```
System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.SR.GetString(String name, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.ValidateSignatureRequirements(SamlMessage samlMessage)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Issue(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequestMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String relayState, String& newSamlSession, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, Boolean isKmsiRequested)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The stacktrace looks like C#, but your tags say java and spring. Add some more background information about the tools you are using and the client (Identity Service) that is trying to interact with the Identity Provider (ADFS).

Answer (score 1):

I got this when my relying party wasn't signing the requests but ADFS was expecting signed requests. It's clearly a bug in the error message creation code in ADFS.

Try turning it off in Power Shell with:

```
Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -TargetIdentifier your-sp-identifier -SignedSamlRequestsRequired $false
```